how to avoid list leaf files in spark streaming json
I've a spark streaming files reading a blob storage with a multiples path and files.

I added the archive option, moving the paths depths to other directory in blob
.option("cleanSource", "archive")
.option("sourceArchiveDir", "wasbs://bronze@xxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/FOLDER/ARCHIVED") 

but the spark continues to list all directories, and it's take 5 minutes. How to avoid ?


To avoid performance issues with Spark continuously listing all directories, narrow down the source path to specific folders and optimize the directory structure. Use options like recursiveFileLookup, maxFilesPerTrigger, and maxBytesPerTrigger to control file processing. Consider using Azure Event Grid or Azure Functions for file notifications instead of relying solely on directory listing.
